# Pandas: Convert Rare Entries in Column to Common Value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame, `df`, with a column called `LocationNormalized`.  I've examined how often each value occurs with `value_counts()` and there are values that occur very rarely.

So I want to convert these rare values to "RARE".  Specifically, if a value occurs in the column less than 10 times, I want to replace it with "RARE".

I was thinking something like:

`df["LocationNormalized"].apply(lambda x: "RARE" if df.value_counts()[x] < 10 else x)`

But I know the `df.value_counts()[x]` syntax isn't correct because `value_counts()` returns a Series.

How would I go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `groupby` + `transform` instead of `value_counts`, it becomes easier to create a mask to set values accordingly.

```
m = df.groupby("LocationNormalized").transform('count').lt(10)
df.loc[m, "LocationNormalized"] = "RARE"
```

---

Demo with a `Series` -

```
s

0    a
1    a
2    a
3    a
4    b
5    b
6    c
7    d
dtype: object

m = s.groupby(s).transform('count').lt(2)  # find objects occurring once
s[m] = 'RARE'

s

0       a
1       a
2       a
3       a
4       b
5       b
6    RARE
7    RARE
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another alternative using list comprehension, but tbh I prefer cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ solution. Using loc with a mask is effective.

```
d = df['LocationNormalized'].value_counts() >= 10

df['LocationNormalized'] = [i if d[i] else 'Rare' for i in df['LocationNormalized']]
```

Comment: Nice one, this should also be fast!